# Trouble with fig.env in knitr?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm having trouble getting fig.env to work in knitr.  Here's a simple example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\begin{document}


<<setup, include=F, cache=F>>=
opts_chunk$set(comment=NA,fig.path=file.path(getwd(),'figure/minimal-'),tidy=F, fig.align='center',size='footnotesize')
options(replace.assign=TRUE, width=60)
@

Hoping for a sideways figure!
<<FIGURE, fig.env='sidewaysfigure',fig.width=10, fig.height=5>>=
plot(1:10,1:10)
@

\end{document}
```

After knitting, all I get in the output .tex file for the figure is

```
{\centering \includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{D:/R/figure/minimal-FIGURE} 

}
```

Any suggestions for what could be going wrong?

sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `fig.cap` option for everything related to the `figure` environment to work, e.g.

```
<<FIGURE, fig.cap='A boring figure.', fig.env='sidewaysfigure', fig.width=10, fig.height=5>>=
plot(1:10,1:10)
@
```